# How to bind an entry to a command?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I am new to programming and i am trying to learn how to command events, now i have an entry but i am not sure how to get the value from the entry in the command. I have debuf it and my value is always null

Xaml

```
   <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,10">
                            <Entry x:Name="numberOfWordsEntry" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding WordAmount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                <Entry.Behaviors>
                                    <EmailValidatorBehavior
                                        x:Name="numberOfWordsVal" />
                                </Entry.Behaviors>
                            </Entry>
                            <avat:RoundedLabel x:Name="numberOfWordsValLabel" IsVisible="False" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions ="End"
                                                Text="{ Translate A_ErrorDailyDoseIsEmpty }" Style="{ StaticResource ValidationEntryErrorStyle }" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <!-- BUTTON Save daily dose -->
                        <StackLayout Spacing="10"
                  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <Button
                        Margin="20,10,20,0"
                       Command ="{Binding SaveNumberCommand}"
                        HeightRequest="44"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             Text="{ Translate A_ButtonSaveDailyDoseDictionarySettings}"
                        />
                        </StackLayout>

  public ICommand SaveNumberCommand { get; private set; }
   public DictionarySetting DictionarySetting { get; set; }
 public DictionarySettingsViewModel()
            : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            LoadData();
            SaveNumberCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveNumber());
            DictionarySetting = new DictionarySetting();

        }

        private async Task SaveNumber()
        {
            this.IsBusy = true;
            DictionarySetting newSetting = new DictionarySetting
            {
                DateSaved = DateTime.Now,
                AmountOfWords = DictionarySetting.AmountOfWords,
            };
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(async () =>
            {
                await AVAT.App.ApiFactory.SaveDictionarySettingAsync(newSetting);

            })).Start();

        }
```

How will I bind the entry value to the command? What I have done returns null as i intiliaze the dictionary settings so it has null, but i am not sure how to access its properties ?

Comment: You don't really need to - the Entry's value is bound to your ViewModel, so you can just get the value you need from the ViewModel property.  OR, you could use the CommandParameter and bind it to the value you want.

Comment: so just  declare private int _amountOfWords; ?

Comment: no, Entry is bound to WordAmount, so just use WordAmount

Comment: I have tied it and it works, thanks!